# getting text inside <p> before and after <strong>

Tags: xpath

Given the example below, how to get all the text / flatten the structure?

```
 <div class="container">
  <p>before_strong
    <strong>inside_strong</strong>
    after_strong
  </p>
  <p>just_p</p>
</div>
```

I tried with the following ones, but they do not return "after_strong", only "before_strong inside_strong":

```
//div//p 
//div/descendant::*
//div/descendant-or-self::*
```

I'm using this with Python + lxml

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? All the text inside `<div>`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Exactly, all the text inside <div>

Comment: Try `//text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options :

```
//div[@class="container"]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output : 4 values (each for one text)

or

```
string(//div[@class="container"])
```

Output : one string

```
before_strong inside_strong after_strong just_p
```